# Where do I find customs in Geometry Dash after pressing "Change custom songs location"?

Tags: geometry-dash

I play Geometry Dash on Mac. I want to replace custom songs, so in the options, I clicked "Change custom songs location". My only question is: how do I *change* the directory for custom songs? Where is it located?

Answer (score 0):

It is located in the Resources folder, and it unsaves all of your previous songs.